# Cycle for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I need some help. I would like to find a way to make a for loop to pass my namespaces inside the jsonpath and using kubectl commands. I tried various ways but got no result. I ran them first for test on the Git Bash terminal.

I'll show you now how I'm trying to do it:

```
for namespace in bike-b2p-old
                  bike-b2p-new; do kubectl get deploy -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"kubectl annotate --overwrite deploy "}{@.metadata.name}{" previous-size="}{@.spec.replicas}{"-n $namespace"}{" \n"}{end}' -n $namespace | sh; done
```

It should add in the annotations previus_size for both namespaces but the terminal gives me an error in execution.

Comment: I've tried various ways to write it but changing a few things. The most common errors I've encountered are:
- error from server(not found): deployments.apps "php-apache" not found

- error: flag needs an argument: 'n' in -n

- cannot parse number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use `kubectl get -o jsonpath` to write out a shell command, and then execute that shell command.  That's very clever, but it also means you're mixing multiple languages and quoting syntaxes in the same string, which can get confusing very quickly.

I'd just write out this algorithm as you expect it to run, without trying to dynamically generate commands:

```
For each Namespace:
  For each Deployment:
    Get its existing replica count
    Create the annotation
```

Translating that into shell syntax:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# For each namespace...
for namespace in bike-b2p-old bike-b2p-new; do
  # For each deployment...
  for deployment in $(kubectl get -n "$namespace" deployment -o name); do
    # ($deployment has the form `deployment/some-name`)

    # Get the existing replica count
    replicas=$(kubectl get -n "$namespace" "$deployment" -o jsonpath='{.spec.replicas}')

    # Set the annotation
    kubectl annotate -n "$namespace" "$deployment" --overwrite "previous-size=$replicas"    
  done
done
```

When you start getting into this level of logic, you may find a higher-level language easier to work with than a shell script; there are [Kubernetes client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) for most popular languages.  Also consider using a tool like Helm that can control the entire YAML file at deployment time rather than using imperative `kubectl annotate` commands that can result in untracked changes.

Comment: I tried what you recommended and it works only that I would like previous_size to be 1 but looking at the annotations of the openlens deploys I see this value: previous-size=.spec.replicas

Comment: I was missing some punctuation in the JSONPath syntax; I've tried to add that in.  This hopefully is an approach that's easier to debug, though, maybe using `sh -x` to see what the script is doing.